# Laravel column missing during seeding

Tags: laravel-9

I'm encountering error during db seeding

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'code ' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `medicines` (`price`, `quantity`, `code` , `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (3831, 23, 12345DFG, 2022-07-30 15:04:29, 2022-07-30 15:04:29))

medicine migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('medicines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("price");
            $table->string("quantity");
            $table->string("code");
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
           
        });
    }
```

model medicine.php

```
class medicine extends Model
{
    use HasFactory,softDeletes;
    protected $fillable=[
        'price',
        'quantity',
        'code',
    ];
}
```

This is the way factory looks like;

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the model's email address should be unverified.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory
     */
    public function unverified()
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'email_verified_at' => null,
            ];
        });
    }
}
```

I use
php artisan db:seed to seed through terminal

Comment: How do you seed? What does your factory look like?

Comment: I have corrected it the problem was in MedicineSeeder.php that had a 'code ' instead of 'code'